# How can I do the hatching shading technique properly?

Tags: pencil-shading

I really like the hatching technique especially with pens, or 'calligraphy pens' but I cant seem to get the style correct, I try to hatch but it ends up not looking properly done.

Are there any techniques that could help me hatch correctly?

Comment: Can you explain your current technique and perhaps include a sample of what your results look like? This will make it easier for us to help "fix" what you're doing wrong, if anything. :D

Comment: How is your general understanding of shading forms? It can be tough to get any of the techniques to look right without understanding the underlying principles.

Comment: so I mean my art teacher says to be more careful with my strokes, I understand that biut how do I make it look good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What are hatching and cross-hatching?

[This article](http://www.asllinea.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Hatching_2.pdf) from the Drawing Magazine explains the basic idea of hatching and cross-hatching:

> At its most basic, *hatching*, also called *hachure*, refers to setting down a pattern of short, rhythmic, parallel lines close together and evenly spaced in order to darken a passage or increase the sense of form in a drawing. The initial “screen” of hatching may be overlaid with subsequent series of lines drawn at contrasting angles, creating crosshatching
> and further darkening the value of the area.

... as well as what they can be used for in art:

> The basic illusion of hatching is that a sequence of separate lines will read as a solid value from a slight distance. With hachure a draftsman can evoke a middle tone, a core or cast shadow or the atmosphere around a figure, as well as provide a means by which disparate elements of a drawing are unified.

### Objectives, techniques, and variations

[This online tutorial](http://thevirtualinstructor.com/hatchingcrosshatching.html) with pictures and videos tells you some of the basic techniques and variations of the art of hatching and cross-hatching. I'll provide some of the most useful quotes for introductory guidance.

- **Hatching**

  > Hatching is created when non-crossing lines are used to indicate the value on or around an object. The value added to the object is dependent on the location of a light source. **More marks are added in the areas of core shadow and cast shadow, while less marks should exist in lighter areas.**
  >
  > When hatching is used, **the lines drawn generally go in the same direction and are mostly parallel with each other**. Sometimes, the lines may curve slightly or even a great bit depending on the contours of the object. Lines of this nature are referred to as cross contour lines.
  >
  > When used correctly, cross contour lines can further the illusion of form by giving the viewer information about the actual 3-dimensional qualities of the object.
  >
  > By changing the frequency of the use of line, and the amount of space between the lines, the artist can create a full range of value in the drawing. Assuming that an artist is working on white paper, **more space between the lines (more paper showing) will lead to lighter values in the drawing. Less space between lines will naturally lead to darker values in the drawing.**
- **Cross hatching**

  > When cross hatching is used, the artist may begin adding value as hatching, but then allow the lines to cross over each other. **The more that the lines cross over each other, the darker the value becomes.**
  >
  > Many artists approach the addition of crossing lines as a science, following a **specific order of vertical lines, followed by horizontal lines, followed by diagonal lines, and so on.**
  >
  > **This method produces very deliberate and controlled marks that are very exact and precise. Others simply cross the lines at random leading to “looser” drawings.** Neither way is better, per se. Some looser approaches work better for some subjects, while more rigid approaches are suitable for other subjects.

For a more visual way of learning how to do hatching and cross-hatching, there are various tutorial videos online. Here's one using a calligraphic pen and ink:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHoqh27vQRw

And another one using a pencil:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxZwO_tIpns

Comment: Sad face for not having YouTube embedding.

Comment: @Catija My thought exactly!

Comment: @Catija - noooo! words are better than sitting through a video that has 30 seconds of information hidden in 5 - 15 - ??? minutes of umms and schmaltz. Worth the effort to type it up. +1